# Quotient ring understanding

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

I just have a conceptual question regarding quotient rings and its elements. To get my point across, I will use the following example:

Consider the quotient ring $\mathbb Z_5[x]/(x+1)^2$. Since the kernel is a square, is there a $b\in \mathbb Z_5[x]/(x+1)^2$ such that $b^2$=0? If yes why is this true?

Comment: How is $(x+1)^2$ an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_5?$

Comment: @user126869: that was a typo on my part! I have fixed it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ a^2 = 0\ $ in $\,R/a^2$

Comment: So, does that mean that $(x+1)$ is our required element?

Comment: @James Yes, or any multiple (though you probably want it to be  nonzero). To be precise, the coset $\ x+1 + (x+1)^2 \Bbb Z_5[x].$

Comment: @James From where did you learn about quotient rings? Good expositions should make things like this fairly obvious.

Comment: Right now I am using Artin. And it has a problem regarding identifying quotient rings. I was planning to use a similar idea on a different quotient ring. So, I just wanted to know whether the above fact was true or not. The quotient ring that I am concerned with is: $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3, 2x+4)$

Comment: @James What are you concerned with in that quotient ring?

Comment: The question just asks for indentifying that quotient ring. So with manipulation I was able to simplify the ring to $\mathbb{Z_2}[x]/((x+1)^2)$ which has four elements. Now, the part that I am stuck on was to identify a map from "suitable" ring to the above quotient ring. I conjuctred it must be $\mathbb{Z_4}$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13244/discussion-between-james-bond-and-bill-dubuque)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$You have the ring $\Z_5[x]$. For any element $a\in \Z_5[X]$ you can consider the ideal generated by this element: $a\Z_5[X]$. Then you can form the quotient ring
$$
\Z_5[X] / a\Z_5[X] = \{f(x) + a\Z_5[X] : f(x) \in \Z_5[X]\}.
$$
This is again a ring under
$$\begin{align}
(f_1(x) + a\Z_5[X]) + (f_2(x) + a\Z_5[X]) &= f_1(x) + f_2(x) + a\Z_5[X]\quad \text{and} \\
(f_1(x) + a\Z_5[X])(f_2(x) + a\Z_5[X]) &= f_1(x)f_2(x) + a\Z_5[X].
\end{align}
$$
So in your example $a = (x+1)^2$. You see that 
$$
\left((x+1) + (x+1)^2\Z_5[x]\right)^2 = (x+1)^2 + (x+1)^2\Z_5[x] = 0 + (x+1)^2\Z_5[x].
$$

Remember that in a ring $R$ with ideal $I$ you have $a + I = b + I$ if and only if $a-b \in I$. In your example you obviously have $(x+1)^2 \in (x+1)^2\Z_5[x]$.